# What's the simplest way to efficiently backup and especially undo UPDATE operations in a MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, backup, restore, operations

I figured it would be easy to just insert a new row in some sort of *history table* using PHP, (containing date, table, column, value etc) on each UPDATE operation, but having MySQL do that automatically in some way would be way more efficient.
Also, the restoring part could be simply a (quite unefficient) PHP script, unless it could be done with a single query (not sure how)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Reference Manual :: Using Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html)